# How to convert date to hex in java

Tags: java

I'm not familiar in java and I need to get current datetime and represent it to a string, e.g.:

```
#1:135790246811221:1:*,00000000,UP,060B08,0D1908#
```

where 060B08 is YYMMDD： GPS date (Nov.8th,2006). 6 characters, in hexadecimal.

and 0D1908 is HHMMSS：   Sending time, 6 characters，in hexadecimal

YYMMDD： Sending date (13:25:08), 6 characters, in hexadecimal, e.g.: : Represents the by 060B08.

I'm trying this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new Date();
String date_str = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", cal.getTime().getYear(), cal.getTime().getMonth(), cal.getTime().getDay());
String hour_str = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", cal.getTime().getHours(), cal.getTime().getMinutes(), cal.getTime().getSeconds());
String content = "#1:" + imei + ":1:*,00000000,UP,"+ date_str.getBytes() +","+ hour_str.getBytes()+"#";
ChannelBuffer buf = ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer();
buf.writeBytes(content.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
channel.write(buf);
```

but is wrong, is returning:

```
#1:359672050130411:1:*,00000000,UP,[B@7f07ff6a,[B@d4dd3b6#
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `getBytes()` calls. It's not clear why they're there to start with...

Comment: What you are attempting to do is called *serialization*. Does it need to be HEX?  There are standard methods in Java for doing this, for example serializing to xml. Then you don't have to think about. It will be standard and your endpoint can read it even if not Java. Also in order to fully serialize a `Calendar` object you'll need to include its timezone as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Calendar.getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) returns a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). 
The [Date.getYear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) is deprecated as also is [Date.getHours()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) and most others.

Ideally you should use [Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) and  Calendar.get([Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)).

Likewise for month, day, minutes and seconds.

Once you have the integer values you can then convert them to hex (where required) using [Integer.toHexString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formatter to format the date and the calculate the hex like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat timeF = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateHex = String.format("%020x", new BigInteger(1, dateF.format(date).getBytes("UTF-8")));
    String timeHex = String.format("%020x", new BigInteger(1, timeF.format(date).getBytes("UTF-8")));
    System.out.println("#1:359672050130411:1:*,00000000,UP," + dateHex + "," + timeHex + "#");
}
```

Output:

```
#1:359672050130411:1:*,00000000,UP,00000000313630333237,00000000313135363130#
```